# Selenium: different content of url between selenium result and browser

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse this [url](http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/jY7ZDoIwFEQ_qde2QV4LxLYCFZAq8kJIXAKRJZFU4euFD3CZeZycyUE5mtuWprqVQ9W15R1lKLcKKVkkfL6CHQ4BmK0022wtDJzM-8kqXM4EXQcAXCUuSOpQLLiDQZJ_aPgQBj_oI8qAFvva7sNxyILJNWk9xa-HF5PQ00SlelTDNTofEu0w1xg6-jOTL6_fjJf9i5MSXXNBfaO16cXzDSnajg4!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSkthWWtLQ2xFS0NsRUpJL29Eb2dBRUlRaGpCS0VRQUNBRVpDZ0dRNEtRcGNFclN0Y1ZhQ0FHTUEvNEMxYjlXX05yeFFERVNaSUpSQ2t5WVNoRVJJX0FBISEvN19JSUFQSEtHMTBPMk0wMEE4TlVBRko2MkdTNS80MDk3MDg5NDgzNjQvYWNOYW1lL2NsaWNrUmVnaXN0ZXIvcmVnTmFtZS9SVVRNQVA!/)

First, I've tried to use `requests` with `bs4`, but result page was differ from content from browser.

```
cont = requests.get(path).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Next I try to use `selenium`:

```
def render_page(path):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(path)
    time.sleep(3)
    r = driver.page_source
    return r

r = render_page(path)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

But it returns another content. Сontent of [page](http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hPT8cAD293QwN_I18DA0cLv1BHNy8zIwN3Y6B8pFm8s7ujh4m5j4GBu1-Qs4GniZOJkYe7k5GBpzExug1wAEcDArrDQa7FbztIHo_5fh75uan6BbmhEQZZJooAhVJN9g!!/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSmdrS0NsRUpDZ3BSQ1NBL29Ob2dBRUlRaGpFS0lRQUJHY1p3aklDa3FTaFNOQkFOYUEhIS80QzFiOVdfTnIwZ0RFU1pJSlJERVNaTUpRaUlrZmchIS83X0lJQVBIS0cxME8yTTAwQThOVUFGSjYyR1M1L25hbjI2MjEzNjAzMDcvaWJtLmludi80MDk3MTE0MjkzOTcvYWNOYW1lL3RyZWVCYWNr/)

After it I've tried add to my code

```
js_code = "return document.getElementsByTagName('html').innerHTML"
your_elements = sel.execute_script(js_code)
```

but it didn't help.

So Are any ways to get content of page using `requests` or `selenium` or maybe some another parser the same as in the browser?

Comment: If the contents of a page are generated / modified using JavaScript, you will not be able to use `requests` and `beautifulsoup4`. You should be able to use `selenium` though. Perhaps try changing the `User-Agent` to match whatever browser you normally use.

Comment: @natiiix should I get the text content also with `selenium`?

Comment: If you want to get the text content, then yes. If you want to get the HTML and then perhaps process it using `bs4`, then perhaps you should HTML source code instead.